# Setting up a SRID to a Leaflet - Geodjango

Tags: django, leaflet, geodjango

I have data in my Postgres DB which are in 31277 projection. 
Anyway, I am using Leaflet map to show them with Geodjango. Right now, my data are moved somewhere down in the map, so I need to change the projection of the Leaflet map.

In documentation (http://django-leaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html) is written just to add SRID attribute to LEAFLET_CONFIG variable, which I did. Like here:

```
LEAFLET_CONFIG = {
    'DEFAULT_ZOOM': 13,
    'MIN_ZOOM': 2,
    'MAX_ZOOM': 18,
    'SRID':31277
}
```

But after I added SRID attribute I got an error when I tried to access to that page with a map:

```
"GET /static/proj4js/31277.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1770
```

Also, I get same error for the WGS84 - 4326

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the path of the error you are getting, that starts with **static** and the documentation of `django-leaflet` on the [CONFIG subject](http://django-leaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html):

> By default, django-leaflet will try to load the spatial reference from your static files at “proj4js/{{ srid }}.js”.

I would suggest configuring your [static file settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) and run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying!  I am not at the home at the moment, so I don't have the project to check. In a few days I will and then I will write to you! :)

Comment: @Neven @John hey, I'm running into a similar issue, did you ever figure this out? For me, running `collectstatic` didn't help :/  While it did create `proj4js.js` and `proj4leaflet.js` in my `STATIC_ROOT` dir, it did not create the `31277.js` file. Is it supposed to, or should I manually add it? And should we really rely on `collectstatic` in development? That seems a bit odd, no?